# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Tags: java, jdbc

I am getting following exception for this sql query in java.

```
 statement2.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO visit_header " 
+ "VALUES ('"+visitnumber+"','"+date+"','"+cookie+"','"+ip+"','"+duration+"','"+pageref
+"','"+startpagename+"','"+endpagename+"','"+pgvw+"','"+starttime+"','"+endtime+"','"
+country+"','"+state+"','"+city+"','"+browser+"','"+os+"','"+device+"')");
```

The exception is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string.
```

I am not getting where i am going wrong.

thank you.

Comment: this one didn't help you??  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766034/literal-does-not-match-format-string-error-on-updating-sql-table

Answer (score 2):

First, you really shouldn't make SQL statements by concatenating Strings.  This leaves you open to SQL injection hacks.  You should be using the PreparedStatement and setting the values, that way JDBC can properly escape them.

The error is most likely due to the starttime and endtime being in the wrong format.  You probably need to show the stack trace as well as some sample data you are trying to insert.  I would suggest trying to put a break right after around this line of code, copying the resulting concatenated String, and running it in your DB directly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in your fields like pgvw contain ' or \, or maybe your date and starttime dose not format before using.